# How to use ng-repeat properly with

Tags: angularjs

In angular, I have an object:

```
$scope.myobj = {
"a":"",
"b":"",
"c":""
}
```

I want to be able to use ng-repeat with ng-model on a text box input such that typing in the textbox will update "a", "b", and "c". Right now my HTML is:

```
<div ng-repeat="(keyname, keyvalue) in myobj">
  <input ng-model="keyvalue" value="{{keyvalue}}">
</div>
```

Comment: try this ` <input ng-model="keyname" >`

Comment: @SSH it populates the text input with... the name of the property, does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this,

```
   <div ng-repeat="(keyname, keyvalue) in myobj">
     <input ng-model="myobj[keyname]" >
   </div>
```

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
$scope.myobj = {
"a":"",
"b":"",
"c":""
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="(keyname, keyvalue) in myobj">
  <input ng-model="myobj[keyname]" >
</div>
 OBJECT VALUES :  {{myobj}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have to change a bit your obj. Make it array (run code snippet)

```js
(function ()
{
    var app = angular.module("app", []);

    function HomeController()
    {
        var vm = this;
        vm.myobj = [{"name":"a"},{"name":"b"},{"name":"c"}];

    }

    app.controller("HomeController", [HomeController]);

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Angular JS App</title>       
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container" ng-controller="HomeController as homeCtrl">

            <div class="row">

                <div ng-repeat="item in homeCtrl.myobj">
                    <input ng-model="item.name" value="{{item.name}}">
                </div>
                {{homeCtrl.myobj | json}}

            </div><!--end of first row-->            
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

use keyname instead of keyvalue.
also give some value to your array keys.
then try with keyvalue also.
it will work for sure

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
   <body>
      <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
         <div ng-repeat="(keyname, keyvalue) in myobj">
            <input ng-model="keyname" value="{{keyvalue}}">
         </div>
      </div>
      <script>
         var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
         app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.myobj = {
         "a":"1",
         "b":"2",
         "c":"3"
         }
         });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```